# How do I prevent a user clicking through an overlay?

Tags: react-native

I have an overlay positioned `absolute`, it has `backgroundColor` and it covers the whole screen. It's overlaying several button components which I can still click on through the overlay.

How do I prevent this behavior? I want to swallow all click events landing on the overlay first.

Code:

```
// Overlay
export default class Overlay extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper} />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        backgroundColor: "black",
        opacity: 0.7
    }
});

// Container
export default class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Overlay />
                <Button onPress={() => this.doSomething()}>
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                </Button>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `pointerEvents`props for *Overlay*: `<View style={styles.wrapper} pointerEvents={'box-only'} />`

Answer (score 1):

Write the absolute position component after other components to render it over the other components.

```
export default class Container extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Button onPress={() => this.doSomething()} title="Hello" />
                    <Overlay />    // provide appropriate height and width to the overlay styles if needed...
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1-  You can try to use Modal component from react-native
- Solution 2- Wrap TouchableWithoutFeedback having blank onPress around your overlay. Don't forget to give full height and width to TouchableWithoutFeedback

something like

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
     <Overlay/>
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback/>
```